# Apply SignalR to ASP.NET Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, startup

I'm trying to make a chatroom for my website(ASP.NET C#). At the beginning, I choose **ASP.NET Web Site** to develop my website instead of the **ASP.NET Web Application**.

Everything seems fine until I tried to apply SignalR.

I have the required references and the `.dll` are also download by **NuGet** at the following path(for example)

```
D:\CL\CL\packages\Microsoft.Owin.2.1.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.dll
```

Now the question is the **Startup.cs**(as shown below)

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(CL.Startup))]

public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

Since my site is created as **ASP.NET Web Site**, it doesn't have a namespace.
Thus, the CL.Startup part makes the following error.

```
    System.EntryPointNotFoundException: The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app.
    - The OwinStartupAttribute.FriendlyName value '' does not match the given value 'CL.Startup' in Assembly 'App_Code.g9dw5cpb, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
    - The given type or method 'CL(1).Startup' was not found. Try specifying the Assembly.
    To disable OWIN startup discovery, add the appSetting owin:AutomaticAppStartup with a value of "false" in your web.config.
    To specify the OWIN startup Assembly, Class, or Method, add the appSetting owin:AppStartup with the fully qualified startup class or configuration method name in your web.config.
```

Does **ASP.NET Web Site** have other way to apply SignalR?
or if there is other suggested  solution to implement chatroom for my website?

thx for reading.

Comment: As far as I know, if an app needs owin to work, it should reference more libraries than just owin itself. Please read this article https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/864725/ASP-NET-Understanding-OWIN-Katana-and-the-Middlewa

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at some of my older signalr projects and I think your missing the OwinStartupAttribute Class and your projects namespace.Call the namespace what your project is called when you first made it and  add attribute to the assembly.

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(CL.Startup))]
namespace CL
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();



        }
    }
}
```

this OwinStartupAttribute Class

is used to mark which class in an assembly should be used for automatic startup.

Comment: Thx for your instant reply! I have tried that too. I have another project created as ASP.NET Web Application can work perfectly fine without needing this OwinStartupAttribute Class.

Besides, it won't work even if I put the following code together.
`[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(CL.Startup))]`
`[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(CL.Startup))]`

Comment: Yeah thats the thing about frameworks, they work fine until they dont lol , I couldnt tell. Yeah best of luck tho.

Comment: Thanks! 

As you said, I thought the mainly problem is that ASP.NET Web Site does not have a namespace. I set up my website using CL for every needed name. So if there is a namespace, CL it must be.

Now I'm working on other way to make my chatroom. (AJAX-based)
If signalR can work, I'm still glad to try it!

Sorry for my poor English, hope you can understand my statement.

Comment: Yeah I can understand you perfectly. Best of luck I have made a small chat client in signalr jquery before. It was fun.